# How do I get the each method to work with multiple inputs using MagicSuggest?

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

I have 3 fields that MagicSuggest will be acting on. I have it set so that when there is a value in the input, a class called 'filled' will activate and leave the label above its respective input. The problem is that this 'filled' class gets added to every other input using MagicSuggest. I just want it for the individual input.

[Here is a pen](http://codepen.io/shimizurei/pen/qzjrA) that contains my problem.

What I have tried:

```
//Try #1
$(maa, baa, laa).each(function(){
  $(maa, baa, laa).on('selectionchange', function(e, m){
    var this = $(this).closest('.ms-ctn');
    $(this).addClass('filled');
  });
});

//Try #2
$(maa).on('selectionchange', function (e, m) {
  $('.ms-sel-ctn').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('.ms-ctn').addClass('filled');
  });
});

//Try #3
$(maa).on('focus', function (c) {
  $('ms-sel-ctn').closest('.ms-ctn').addClass('filled');
});

//Try #4
$('.magsug').each(function () {
  var xxx = $(this).magicSuggest({});
  $(xxx).on('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection) {
    $('.ms-sel-ctn').closest('.ms-ctn').addClass('filled');
  });
});

//Try #5
$('.magsug').each(function () {
  var ms = $(this).magicSuggest({});
  $(ms).on('selectionchange', function (e, m) {
    $('.ms-sel-ctn').each(function(){
      $(this).closest('.ms-ctn').addClass('filled');
    });
  });
});
```

I found a similar question on the [issues](https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest/issues/46) page in github and tried to implement it (Try #5), but it didn't work for me. I'm learning JavaScript, so sorry for any apparent errors. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying all input fields at once, which is why you have the issue.

You should be using the events and methods provided by the component:

- `on('selectionchange')` is triggered when a selection changes
- `ms.getValue()` returns the value contained in the component.

Anyways, here is your pen corrected:

http://codepen.io/bubbliscious/pen/fecji

Cheers